# Search and Modify Column in Large CSV FIle

Tags: windows, perl, unix, sed, awk

I have some large CSV file with the following format ( separated by comma )

```
2014.03.11 14:59:59.146,67.1547,67.15507,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.206,67.15405,67.15437,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.506,67.15552,67.15589,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.707,67.15581,67.15616,0.02,0.02
```

Now I would like to accomplish this task.

- Multiple 100 to the Column 2 and 3

Result should look like

```
2014.03.11 14:59:59.146,6715.47,6715.507,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.206,6715.405,6715.437,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.506,6715.552,6715.589,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.707,6715.581,6715.616,0.02,0.02
```

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{$2*=100;$3*=100}1' FS=, OFS=, file
2014.03.11 14:59:59.146,6715.47,6715.51,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.206,6715.4,6715.44,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.506,6715.55,6715.59,0.02,0.02
2014.03.11 14:59:59.707,6715.58,6715.62,0.02,0.02
```

You can use `$2=$2*100` or just `$2*=100` to multiply a column by `100`

Comment: You are welcome, if answer is what you like, please accept it, by selecting the check box next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F/,/ -lape "$F[$_] *= 100 for (1,2); $_ = join',', @F;" < input.csv > output.csv
```